# How to wait to Snackbar ? I want to know when it is closed

Tags: android, snackbar

I want to get informed when Snackbar is closed. 
In an activity I use `Snackbar` and then I call another activity and I want to show `Snackbar` and when it has been already closed want to `startActivity(NextActivity)`.
 How could I manage it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Some text", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                    super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);

                    startActivity(this, NextActivity.class);
                }
            }).show();
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I show the Snackbar ? It doesn't appear.

Comment: @MishoZhghenti Sorry, I forgot to add '.show()' after the code :)

Comment: @MishoZhghenti I'm using app, seems can't edit my answer now. Just add ".show()".

Comment: I tried to write show() another place, so I didn't understand why it was so :)

Comment: `.setCallback()` is depreciated. Simply replace it with `.addCallback()`; it worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Define an action

```
.setAction("Go To Next Activity", mOnClickListener);
```

define onClickListenet as follows:

```
mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                snackBar.dismiss(); // to close the snackbar
                // startActivity(nextActivityIntent)
            }
        };
```

[More Info Here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-snackbar-example/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm late but I hope it works for you

```
Scaffold.of(thisContext).showSnackBar(snackBar).closed.then((value){
   print('snackbar closed');
});
```